# Java: Can't find symbol: class name, when the class name in one of two packages with the same name

Tags: java, class, testing

I'm writing Junit test method for a project using Eclipse. There are two packages with the same name as shown below. Class_1 only exists in one of them. When I import this class in another class that is located in another project, the compiler says the class cannot be found.

Project 1
src/test/java:
au.com.test.common.package1.Class_1

src/main/java:
au.com.test.common.package1.
there is no Class_1 in this package1

Project 2
src/test/java:
au.com.test.client.packagename.Class_2
imports au.com.test.common.package1.Class_1;

When I maven build the test by />mvn test, the compiler generates error saying Cannot find the symbol.  How do I fix this issue please?
Many thanks.

Comment: Please add the relevant source code as well.

Comment: `compiler-construction` is not an appropriate tag for this question.

Comment: Hi Tim Biegeleisen, it's just an access or dependency issue and I don't think the source codes are relevant here. Thanks Rodge

Comment: What is the class access specifier??

Comment: test sources are not exported to other projects. Everything in `src/test` is **not** accessible in other projects. The point of test sources is to test the project, not to be used as a dependency.